# Print Line Starting with a String

Tags: python

I have a file that prints line by line if `match` is in line, and if the string `"Expected"` is in line. However, I want the line to start with `match` instead of the actual beginning of the line.

This is the code I have

```
F = open(path,'r')
writestring = ''
for line in F:
    if match in line:
        if 'Expected' in line:
            writestring = writestring+line+'\n'
```

Comment: `if line.startswith('Expected'):`

Comment: I have tried that and it did not work since the lines do not start with match or "expected"

Comment: Then you need to explain more clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: `if line.startswith(match)`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to print a _substring_ of the line starting from `match`?

Comment: The lines are very long. 
Example of a line:
`[2020-Aug-01 19:51:25.337][C][TAL][DUT: 188703_772_1][8948][DiagsLogger::Error, Line 90]match Expected: 8.041418; Actual: -0.029907`

I want to only print 
`match Expected: 8.041418; Actual: -0.029907`
Not the whole thing

Comment: khelwood, yes!!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to find a substring of each line and print it instead of the entire line. I suggest you learn about regular expressions and capturing groups. You can use this to find a specific part of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print `line` starting from the point where `match` occurs, you can do this:

```
print(line[line.index(match):])
```

`line.index(match)` returns the index where `match` occurs in `line`, and `line[line.index(match):]` is the substring from that index to the end of the string.